# How to handle malformed string array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am extracting information from a `csv`. In that one cell has a value which is `[SQ03er1]`. Clearly it is a string array but the element inside itself doesn't contain quotes. So when I try to do something like this

```
from ast import literal_eval

string_array = '[SQ03er1]'
array = literal_eval(string_array)
```

The error thrown below is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(str(literal_eval(check)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 60, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

How do I handle such a value?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: E. g. using a regular expression to check the format and extract the data. The details depend on the precise format used for these arrays.

Comment: @PrateekDewan It should be a regular array like `['SQ03er1']`

Comment: do you always have a single value, or there could be several values like `[a c d]` ?

Comment: You'd probably have to use a regular expression in that case. Your expression `'[SQ03er1]'` is missing quotes inside of the square braces, hence the `literal_eval` will fail. It would've worked only if the expression looked like `'["SQ03er1"]'`.

Comment: @lenik yes it will always be a single value.

Comment: why do you call it a `string array`, then?

Comment: @lenik its supposed to be an array with a single value `["SQ03er1"]`. This is what I need.

Comment: "Clearly it is a string array" Why is this clear? Certainly it is possible for strings to have square-bracket symbols in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try this:

```
>>> string_array = '[SQ03er1]'
>>> array = string_array[1:-1]
>>> print array
SQ03er1
>>> array = [string_array[1:-1]]
>>> print array
['SQ03er1']
>>>
```

Comment: oh wow! Why didn't I think about this? Just manipulate the string itself! I will accept this.